# Class not found exception in Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Hi I am using the following code from this site: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

But when I am running it it showing exception **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: A**
May be I am going somewhere wrong Please help.
Here is the code:

```
package com.Test;  
  class A {}

public class instance1 {
       public static void main(String args[])
       {
          try {
             Class cls = Class.forName("A");
            System.out.println("gfsdga");
             boolean b1 
               = cls.isInstance(new Integer(37));
             System.out.println(b1);
             boolean b2 = cls.isInstance(new A());
             System.out.println(b2);
          }
          catch (Throwable e) {
             System.err.println(e);
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: The previous answers are correct, nothing to add except that your package names should be all lowercase. It's the Java convention, and sticking to conventions makes the coding world a little brighter.

Comment: Thanks pcalcao...I will keep in mind

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The class is actually called `com.Test.A` because you've declared it within the `com.Test` package - `Class.forName()` takes the package-qualified class name. (Note that `com.Test` is a pretty odd package name, too.)

Comment: Oh dat was too fast....Thanks Jon.Yes Jon I know package name is pretty odd but I am learning Java reflection now thats why I have just taken any package name

Answer (score 6):

You need `Class.forName("com.Test.A")` instead.